# generate python models from k8s CRDs

Tags: python, kubernetes, automation, cross-platform, code-generation

I'm trying to use python to add/delete/get status of CRDs. Since the official SDK provides only generic functions to deal with CRD, i want to implement my own wrapper to manage those particular CRDs ( mainly crossplane ones)

is there a way to generate Python models ideally with validation from a yaml CRD file like this one: https://github.com/crossplane-contrib/provider-gcp/blob/master/package/crds/cache.gcp.crossplane.io_cloudmemorystoreinstances.yaml